# Posting and reading metadata with D jango rest framework json api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, json-api

I'm using Django rest framework json api and I'm trying to post some meta data in my JSON:API POST request.

```
let user = {
    data: {
        type: "User",
        attributes: {
            type: "individual",
            status: "active"
        },
        relationships: {
            individual: {
                data: {
                    type: "Individual",
                    id: applicant.id
                }
            }
        },
        meta: {
            message: vm.createApplicantAccountMessage 
        } // <------ This is the meta info
    }
};
JsonApiService.create('users', user);
```

But I cant figure out how to read it inside my viewset `perform_create` function.

```
class UserViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.none()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filterset_class = UserFilterSet

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # TODO: Find out how to read what is inside the meta message here
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `BaseViewSet` inherited from `viewsets.ModelViewSet` or at least `mixins.CreateModelMixin` then you can override `create` method. For example;

```
class UserViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.none()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filterset_class = UserFilterSet

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data) # <- you can see coming data with request.data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        # if you do not have custom logic then you can simply return super()
        # return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```